# quickly evaluate the simplex volume in a large group of points

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, determinant, simplex

Suppose there are *n* points in *m* dimention (*n < m*), and *p+1* points are selected to form a simplex (*p+1 < n < m*, *p+1 << m*).

The *p* simplex volume is determined by [Cayley-Menger Determinant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cayley-MengerDeterminant.html):

$V^2 = \frac{-1}{(-2)^p (p!)^2} \det(C)$,

while C is $\pmatrix{0&e^T\\ e&B}$, and B is a (p+2)*(p+2) pair-wise distance matrix with a top row (0,1,...,1) and a left column (0,1,...,1)^T.

Now I want to replace the point $p_1$ in *p* with a point in {n-p} to maximize the volume, while keep other points unchanged. A straightforward way is to calculate det(C) for every point in {n - p},
but it might be slow if the set of {n-p} is huge.

I could exclude  points in the original simplex hull (simplex with $p_1$), however there might be not many 
points exactly lay inside/on the simplex hull.

Are there ideas on how to quickly filter out points in {n-p}?

Comment: Is $m$ so large that it would be unreasonable to generate an orthonormal basis for the subspace normal to the plane generated by the $p$ vertices other than $p_1$? If so, you can optimize the volume by applying a single subtraction and a single linear transformation to the points and optimizing the resulting magnitudes.

Comment: @Kajelad m is much larger than p, e.g., m > 5000 while p < 20. Could  you provide more details on how to do the optimization? I am new to geometry.

Comment: There is a useful recurrence relation for the n-simplex, outlined [here](http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath664/kmath664.htm). Basically, for an n-simplex with vertices $\vec v_1,\vec v_2, ...,\vec v_n$, the volume can be expressed as: $$V_n=\frac h{n-1}V_{n-1}$$ Where $V_{n-1}$ is the "base" of the n-simplex, the volume of the (n-1)-simplex formed by omitting a particular vertex $\vec v_1$, and $h$ is the "height" or the n-simplex, the least squares distance from $\vec v_1$ to the affine span of the remaining vertices. It seemed like this might be useful for your problem.

Comment: @Kajelad For me the problem is how to calculate the "height" to the affine span. I think it is called as perpendicular distance? Do you have some idea onhow to get this distance, or evaluate the relate value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a set of $n$ points in $\mathbb R^m$, we generate a (p-1)-simplex $S_{p-1}$ with vertices $\{\vec v_1,\vec v_2,...,\vec v_p\}$. By choosing another affinely independent point $\vec v_{p+1}$, we can generate a new p-siplex $S_p$. We have many choices of $\vec v_{p+1}$, and we want to find the one that maximizes the volume of $S_p$.

To do this, we can use a recurrence relation for the volume of simplices. Letting $V_p$ and $V_{p-1}$ be the volumes of $S_p$ and $S_{p-1}$ respectively, we have:

$$V_p=\frac hpV_{p-1}$$

Where $h$ is the "height" of $\vec v_{p+1}$ above the base.

Let $A$ be the affine span of $\{\vec v_1,\vec v_2,...,\vec v_p\}$ (the p-1 dimensional hyperplane containing all the points). If we choose any point in the span, such as $\vec v_p$, and subtract it from all of our points (this is a translation that does not affect the geometry of the problem), then A becomes a subspace (Which I'll call B) spanned by $\{\vec v_1-\vec v_p,\vec v_2-\vec v_p,...,\vec v_{p-1}-\vec v_p\}$. Also, the vector $\vec v_{p+1}-\vec v_p$ points from a point on the subspace to $v_{p+1}$.

We can thus find $h$ by finding the component of $v_{p+1}-v_p$ perpendicular to B. That is,

$$h=\left|\text{proj}_{B^\perp}(\vec v_{p+1}-\vec v_p)\right|=\left|\vec v_{p+1}-\vec v_p-\text{proj}_B(\vec v_{p+1}-\vec v_p)\right|$$

Since $m>>p$ (and thus $B^\perp$ is much higher dimensional than $B$), the second expression is more useful. The projection operator $\text{proj}_B$ can be expressed as a matrix $P$.

$$P=B(B^TB)^{-1}B^T$$

Where $B$ denotes a matrix whose columns are $\vec v_1-\vec v_p,\vec v_2-\vec v_p,...,\vec v_{p-1}-\vec v_p$. This gives us a compact expression for $h$.

$$h=\left|(I-P)(\vec v_{p+1}-\vec v_p)\right|$$

Since $I-P$ depends only on $\vec v_1-\vec v_p,\vec v_2-\vec v_p,...,\vec v_{p-1}-\vec v_p$, it only needs to be computed once. Finding $h^2$ for a particular choice of $v_{p+1}$ will require one matrix-vector multiplication and one dot product, and the choice that maximizes $h^2$ necessarily maximizes the volume.

Comment: could you kindly provide links on how to get h in the second equation for the first and second expression?

Comment: Is there something about my simplification that doesn't make sense? The basic idea is that $\vec v_{p+1}-\vec v_p$ has a component parallel to the plane and a component normal to the plane, so we can subtract off the parallel component (which we find with a projection operator) to find the normal component, whose magnitude is $h$.  [This PDF](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/417/OrthoProj.pdf) provides a bit of background as to why the matrix expression I use for the projection operator works.

Comment: Thanks for the pdf! I will compare with the method with Cayley-Menger Determinant and report later.

Comment: I have two extent questions @Kajelad. From defined vector space, if the distance h is 0, then the point $V_{p+1}$ is in the vector space B, right? Second, If I want to know whether this point is the **orignal simplex hull** $S_{p-1}$, which additional requirements are needed? Is it sufficient that the Euclidean distance of  $V_{p+1} - V_{p}$ is smaller than all vertices in B?

Comment: if the height is zero, $\vec v_p+1$ lies in the same hyperplane as the rest of the points. Determining if the point lies in the convex hull of the remaining points is a more difficult problem. your condition won't work, since $\vec v_p$ is generally one of the vertices of the hull. The most common method is to set up a Linear Programming Feasibility Problem, or just enumerate the faces. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901959/find-if-a-point-is-inside-a-convex-hull-for-a-set-of-points-without-computing-th) might be a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks! I found one useful link for the inhull test with R ([link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-December/414638.html))